# multiply fields based on a field value in sql

Tags: sql

I have this kind of table:

```
name,code1,code2
a,3,
b,5,
c,10,
a,,10
b,,30
c,,50
```

**EDIT**

My table is like this and I will always have two rows with the same value in field `name`:

[image: My table]

and I would like to multiply rows having the same value on `name` field, so getting something like this:

```
name,final
a,30
b,150
c,500
```

I was also thinking to transform the previous table into this one:
[image]

Comment: Do you always want to multiple values from `code1` with values from `code2`? What if you have three rows for  the same name (instead of two) - what should be the result then?  It's also unclear to me what the `,,` in the sample data means. Do those rows have no value for `code1`? What if they *do* have a value? What do you want to multiply then?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name my table is like the one showed in the example I will always have two rows for the same name. and `,,`means the code1 is missing

Comment: In the final result you meant to put `a,300` and `c,400`, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the below -

```
select name, min(code1)*min(code2) as final
from tablename
group by name
```

Comment: this solution is working, but not always I don't understand why

Comment: @stackfac, can you show me in which case this is not working

Comment: sorry it is working properly, but I had to change type from integer to long. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

If you **always** have two rows for each name where one (only) has a value for code1 and the other (only) has a value for code2, you can use a self join

```
select t1.name, t1.code1, t2.code2, t1.code1 * t2.code2
from the_table t1 
  join the_table t2 on t1.name = t2.name and t2.code1 is null
where t1.code2 is null;
```

Comment: it is a more bit tricky than this, because I am using a graphdb. Thanks anyway!

Comment: Then why did you tag your question with `postgresql`?

Comment: because I thought it was an easy thing and I was also thinking that tagging with the right tag no one was going to help me

Comment: Well, I was about to post an answer on how to create a custom aggregate in Postgres - that wouldn't have helped you a bit then. You should never tag your questions with unrelated things. My query should work just like the accepted answer - if it does not this "graphdb" has a really poor SQL implementation.

Answer (score 0):

SQL does not have a built-in "product" aggregation function.  But you can go back to arithmetic, and use logarithms for this.  The exact syntax might vary by database, but hte idea is:

```
select name, exp(sum(ln(code1))) as product
from t
group by name;
```

All your examples are positive.  This becomes a bit more complicated if you have to deal with negative or zero values.

Comment: can I just transform the table into:
`name,code1,code2
a,3,10
b,5,150`

Comment: @stackfac . . . I don't understand your comment.  This returns the data as described by the question.  It is not a good idea to transform tables in place, but you can save the results to a new table if you like.

Comment: @GordonLinoff: I think `code1` should be multiplied with `code2` but the sample data is a bit confusing